# How can remove this window screen to repair it?

Tags: repair, windows, screens

My friend's dog tore through the window screen. I can't seem to get the screen off--it has no pullable tabs and no bottom levers to help pull it out. The house seems to be new and I'm hoping that this isn't one of those windows where you have to replace the WHOLE THING just to get a new screen.

Follow the link to the pictures https://plus.google.com/u/0/115787094028199748730

[image]

Even if you could just tell me the model of the window, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! Can you post the pictures on something other than your personal google account, like imgur?

Comment: Many times there is a spring loaded edge and you can physically push in the frame on that edge with one hand while manipulating the opposite edge out with the other using a small screw driver to aid if things are tight.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty standard screen repair. You need to remove the spline to get the screen out, which can be done with an awl or a narrow flat-head screwdriver.

[image]

You'll need a new screen, spline, a spline install tool (under $10), and a sharp utility knife.

It's not very dificult, but does take some patience.

---

It looks like this is a fixed window, so you'd have to install in place.

[image]

Position the new screen, and then push the spline into the channel, pulling the screen tight as you go. I'd start with the top edge.

It's critical to get the first edge straight. Start with enough spline sticking out so you can wrap it down both sides, and on one side, also run back along the bottom. You should end up with a single piece of spline with the ends in one corner (though this isn't crtical, and if you have to cut it that's fine).

Work your way down both sides at the same time, keeping it tight as you go, then finally install the bottom edge.

Finally, cut the excess screen off using the knife.

[image]

---

Here's a full guide (and the source of these pictures): http://www.familyhandyman.com/windows/repair/how-to-fix-a-window-screen/view-all

Comment: I think the question involves removing the screen frame from the window unit. Sometimes that's tricky and requires removal of a sash.

Comment: Hm, I suppose I jumped to the conclusion this was asked as an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/148221), so fair enough.

Comment: Even if you can't get the screen out, just destroy the darned thing and make a new one. It's pretty easy as @gregmac describes.

Comment: I just learned a new way to *install a screen saver*...