# Replacing net screens

Tags: duct-tape

I would like to replace a few mosquito net screens at my house. I was quoted with 130$ each and I have to replace 8 of them. After some research I can get the net for quite cheap. However the current system has it's own "lock" that has the net "glued" on it, so I would like to find out what kind of tape I am supposed to use to cut the old net, replace it with a new one and "glue" it on stock lock base.

I am attaching some pictures to make understanding easier. I am sorry for my english it's not my native.[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There's usually a spline that holds the screen on the "outside" side, set into a channel. It looks kind of like a rope, and is usually made of vinyl -- though when it's installed in the channel it does sort of look like a thick bead of glue. Is that what you're referring to? Can you take a picture from the outside? (eg: [see my answer here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/102605/157))

Comment: Just screen. "Net screen" is redundant.

Comment: @gregmac this is a roll screen. It has some kind of roll mechanism on the top. The bottom part locks to a hook shaped lock.